# HTTP Error 403: Forbidden with urlretrieve

Tags: python, http, python-requests, urllib

I am trying to download a PDF, however I get the following error: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

I am aware that the server is blocking for whatever reason, but I cant seem to find a solution.

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import requests


def download_pdf(url):

full_name = "Test.pdf"
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, full_name)


try: 
url =         ('http://papers.xtremepapers.com/CIE/Cambridge%20IGCSE/Mathematics%20(0580)/0580_s03_qp_1.pdf')

print('initialized')

hdr = {}
hdr = {
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2)     AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36',
'Content-Length': '136963',
}



print('HDR recieved')

req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers=hdr)

print('Header sent')

resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)

print('Request sent')

respData = resp.read()

download_pdf(url)


print('Complete')

except Exception as e:
print(str(e))
```

Comment: If the server is blocking, there's probably not an easy way through. Forbidden means that you are not allowed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTTP Error 403: Forbidden while downloading file using urllib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45358126/http-error-403-forbidden-while-downloading-file-using-urllib)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You seem to have already realised this; the remote server is apparently checking the user agent header and rejecting requests from Python's urllib. But `urllib.request.urlretrieve()` doesn't allow you to change the HTTP headers, however, you can use [`urllib.request.URLopener.retrieve()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.URLopener.retrieve):

```
import urllib.request

opener = urllib.request.URLopener()
opener.addheader('User-Agent', 'whatever')
filename, headers = opener.retrieve(url, 'Test.pdf')
```

N.B. You are using Python 3 and these functions are now considered part of the ["Legacy interface"](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/urllib.request.html#legacy-interface), and `URLopener` has been deprecated. For that reason you should not use them in new code.

The above aside, you are going to a lot of trouble to simply access a URL. Your code imports [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/), but you don't use it - you should though because it is much easier than `urllib`. This works for me:

```
import requests

url = 'http://papers.xtremepapers.com/CIE/Cambridge%20IGCSE/Mathematics%20(0580)/0580_s03_qp_1.pdf'
r = requests.get(url)
with open('0580_s03_qp_1.pdf', 'wb') as outfile:
    outfile.write(r.content)
```

Comment: While a good point - It doesn't explain the reason for the 403 error.

Comment: The question was not asking for reason.