# HTTP Error 403: Forbidden while downloading file using urllib

Tags: python-3.x, file, download, urllib

I have this line of code: `urllib.request.urlretrieve('http://lolupdater.com/downloads/LPB.exe', 'LPBtest.exe')`, but when I run it, it throws an error `urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That looks to be an actual HTTP `403: Forbidden` error. Python `urllib` throws the exception when it encounters an HTTP status code (documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.error.html#urllib.error.HTTPError)). `403` in general means: "The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it." You will need to add HTTP headers to identify yourself and avoid the `403` error, documentation on [Python urllib headers](https://docs.python.org/3.1/howto/urllib2.html#headers). Here is an example using `urlopen`:

```
import urllib.request
req = urllib.request.Request('http://lolupdater.com/downloads/LPB.exe', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
```

With Python 3 `urllib.urlretrieve()` is [considered legacy](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/urllib.request.html#legacy-interface). I would recommend [Python Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) for this, here is a working example:

```
import requests

url = 'http://lolupdater.com/downloads/LPB.exe'
r = requests.get(url)
with open('LPBtest.exe', 'wb') as outfile:
    outfile.write(r.content)
```

Comment: But how to save the data than if I have an executable?

Comment: @JakubBláha I updated my answer. It looks like `urllib.urlretrieve()` doesn't allow you to set headers. I would recommend using Python Requests, its definitely the more accepted way to do what you are trying to do, hope it helps.

Comment: i got "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:"  , for both solutions...

Answer (score 0):

If youre downloading a pdf using urllib, you might get the 403 error due to not having specified headers. To fix this and download any pdf file with its link use:

```
headers={"User-Agent": "_ANY_USER"}
pdf_response = requests.get(pdf_url, headers=headers)
with open(f'C:/Users/username/path/{file_name}.pdf', 
'wb') as f:
f.write(pdf_response.content)
```