# How to get chosen class images from Imagenet?

Tags: imagenet

## Background

I have been playing around with `Deep Dream` and `Inceptionism`, using the `Caffe` framework to visualize layers of `GoogLeNet`, an architecture built for the `Imagenet` project, a large visual database designed for use in visual object recognition.

You can find `Imagenet` here: [Imagenet 1000 Classes.](https://gist.github.com/yrevar/942d3a0ac09ec9e5eb3a)

---

To probe into the architecture and generate 'dreams', I am using three notebooks:

1. **https://github.com/google/deepdream/blob/master/dream.ipynb**
2. **https://github.com/kylemcdonald/deepdream/blob/master/dream.ipynb**
3. **https://github.com/auduno/deepdraw/blob/master/deepdraw.ipynb**

---

The basic idea here is to extract some features from each channel in a specified layer from the model or a 'guide' image.

Then we input an image we wish to modify into the model and extract the features in the same layer specified (for each octave),
enhancing the best matching features, i.e., the largest dot product of the two feature vectors.

---

So far I've managed to modify input images and control dreams using the following approaches:

> - **(a) applying layers as `'end'` objectives for the input image optimization.** (see [Feature Visualization](https://distill.pub/2017/feature-visualization/appendix/googlenet/4c.html))
> - **(b) using a second image to guide de optimization objective on the input image.**
> - **(c) visualize `Googlenet` model classes generated from noise**.

---

However, the effect I want to achieve sits in-between these techniques, of which I haven't found any documentation, paper, or code.

### **Desired result** (not part of the question to be answered)

> **To have *one single class or unit* belonging to a given `'end'` layer (a) guide the optimization objective (b) and have this class visualized (c) on the input image:**

An example where `class = 'face'` and `input_image = 'clouds.jpg'`:

[image]
*please note: the image above was generated using a model for face recognition, which was not trained on the `Imagenet` dataset. For demonstration purposes only.*

---

### Working code

> Approach (a)

```
from cStringIO import StringIO
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage as nd
import PIL.Image
from IPython.display import clear_output, Image, display
from google.protobuf import text_format
import matplotlib as plt    
import caffe
         
model_name = 'GoogLeNet' 
model_path = 'models/dream/bvlc_googlenet/' # substitute your path here
net_fn   = model_path + 'deploy.prototxt'
param_fn = model_path + 'bvlc_googlenet.caffemodel'
   
model = caffe.io.caffe_pb2.NetParameter()
text_format.Merge(open(net_fn).read(), model)
model.force_backward = True
open('models/dream/bvlc_googlenet/tmp.prototxt', 'w').write(str(model))
    
net = caffe.Classifier('models/dream/bvlc_googlenet/tmp.prototxt', param_fn,
                       mean = np.float32([104.0, 116.0, 122.0]), # ImageNet mean, training set dependent
                       channel_swap = (2,1,0)) # the reference model has channels in BGR order instead of RGB

def showarray(a, fmt='jpeg'):
    a = np.uint8(np.clip(a, 0, 255))
    f = StringIO()
    PIL.Image.fromarray(a).save(f, fmt)
    display(Image(data=f.getvalue()))
  
# a couple of utility functions for converting to and from Caffe's input image layout
def preprocess(net, img):
    return np.float32(np.rollaxis(img, 2)[::-1]) - net.transformer.mean['data']
def deprocess(net, img):
    return np.dstack((img + net.transformer.mean['data'])[::-1])
      
def objective_L2(dst):
    dst.diff[:] = dst.data 

def make_step(net, step_size=1.5, end='inception_4c/output', 
              jitter=32, clip=True, objective=objective_L2):
    '''Basic gradient ascent step.'''

    src = net.blobs['data'] # input image is stored in Net's 'data' blob
    dst = net.blobs[end]

    ox, oy = np.random.randint(-jitter, jitter+1, 2)
    src.data[0] = np.roll(np.roll(src.data[0], ox, -1), oy, -2) # apply jitter shift
            
    net.forward(end=end)
    objective(dst)  # specify the optimization objective
    net.backward(start=end)
    g = src.diff[0]
    # apply normalized ascent step to the input image
    src.data[:] += step_size/np.abs(g).mean() * g

    src.data[0] = np.roll(np.roll(src.data[0], -ox, -1), -oy, -2) # unshift image
            
    if clip:
        bias = net.transformer.mean['data']
        src.data[:] = np.clip(src.data, -bias, 255-bias)

 
def deepdream(net, base_img, iter_n=20, octave_n=4, octave_scale=1.4, 
              end='inception_4c/output', clip=True, **step_params):
    # prepare base images for all octaves
    octaves = [preprocess(net, base_img)]
    
    for i in xrange(octave_n-1):
        octaves.append(nd.zoom(octaves[-1], (1, 1.0/octave_scale,1.0/octave_scale), order=1))
    
    src = net.blobs['data']
    
    detail = np.zeros_like(octaves[-1]) # allocate image for network-produced details
    
    for octave, octave_base in enumerate(octaves[::-1]):
        h, w = octave_base.shape[-2:]
        
        if octave > 0:
            # upscale details from the previous octave
            h1, w1 = detail.shape[-2:]
            detail = nd.zoom(detail, (1, 1.0*h/h1,1.0*w/w1), order=1)

        src.reshape(1,3,h,w) # resize the network's input image size
        src.data[0] = octave_base+detail
        
        for i in xrange(iter_n):
            make_step(net, end=end, clip=clip, **step_params)
            
            # visualization
            vis = deprocess(net, src.data[0])
            
            if not clip: # adjust image contrast if clipping is disabled
                vis = vis*(255.0/np.percentile(vis, 99.98))
            showarray(vis)

            print octave, i, end, vis.shape
            clear_output(wait=True)
            
        # extract details produced on the current octave
        detail = src.data[0]-octave_base
    # returning the resulting image
    return deprocess(net, src.data[0])
```

**I run the code above with:**

```
end = 'inception_4c/output'
img = np.float32(PIL.Image.open('clouds.jpg'))
_=deepdream(net, img)
```

> Approach (b)

```
"""
Use one single image to guide 
the optimization process.

This affects the style of generated images 
without using a different training set.
"""

def dream_control_by_image(optimization_objective, end):
    # this image will shape input img
    guide = np.float32(PIL.Image.open(optimization_objective))  
    showarray(guide)
  
    h, w = guide.shape[:2]
    src, dst = net.blobs['data'], net.blobs[end]
    src.reshape(1,3,h,w)
    src.data[0] = preprocess(net, guide)
    net.forward(end=end)

    guide_features = dst.data[0].copy()
    
    def objective_guide(dst):
        x = dst.data[0].copy()
        y = guide_features
        ch = x.shape[0]
        x = x.reshape(ch,-1)
        y = y.reshape(ch,-1)
        A = x.T.dot(y) # compute the matrix of dot-products with guide features
        dst.diff[0].reshape(ch,-1)[:] = y[:,A.argmax(1)] # select ones that match best

    _=deepdream(net, img, end=end, objective=objective_guide)
```

**and I run the code above with:**

```
end = 'inception_4c/output'
# image to be modified
img = np.float32(PIL.Image.open('img/clouds.jpg'))
guide_image = 'img/guide.jpg'
dream_control_by_image(guide_image, end)
```

## Question

**Now the failed approach how I *tried* to access individual classes, hot encoding the matrix of classes and focusing on one (so far to no avail):**

```
def objective_class(dst, class=50):
   # according to imagenet classes 
   #50: 'American alligator, Alligator mississipiensis',
   one_hot = np.zeros_like(dst.data)
   one_hot.flat[class] = 1.
   dst.diff[:] = one_hot.flat[class]
```

To make this clear: the question is not about the dream code, which is the interesting *background* and which is already working code, but it is about this last paragraph's question only: **Could someone please guide me on how to get images of a chosen class (take class `#50: 'American alligator, Alligator mississipiensis'`) from ImageNet** (so that I can use them as input - together with the cloud image - to create a dream image)?

Comment: As a start, have you considered reducing the standard 1000 classes to just 1 class to get just one class as output? Mind that GoogLeNet happens to have three classification layers: "loss1/classifier", "loss2/classifier" and "loss3/classifier, and you have to change num_output = 1 in all three layers, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36841158/fine-tuning-of-googlenet-model. What is more, if you just want to build new images from 2 different classes (clouds and face), perhaps you use a GAN and take the two classes as input (instead of guiding the optimization objective with the clouds).

Comment: @8-Bit Borges, does the question still need an answer or is issue resolved?

Comment: Still active. Not resolved yet.

Comment: Is it understood correctly that your question is not about how to apply Deep Dream, since you already seem to present a working core code, and that the question is just in the very last paragraph of your question: how to pick an individually chosen class from the output of GoogLeNet?

Comment: Yes, you understood correctly.

Comment: As a beginner at DL, I just try to understand it. I had a look at https://gist.github.com/joelouismarino/a2ede9ab3928f999575423b9887abd14 --> "googlenet.py". GoogLeNet is a pretrained supervised learning model: input is e.g. `cat.jpg` and you get out its predicted class, and you do not need to have all of the input images and labels that GoogLeNet uses to train and test itself. That is the advantage of the pretrained models. Instead, you want to filter the ImageNet input images classified as #50 in https://gist.github.com/yrevar/942d3a0ac09ec9e5eb3a. Thus, is this a pure ImageNet question?

Comment: That is why your question seems not to be about the three classifications that GoogLeNet gives you in line 199 `out = model.predict(img) # note: the model has three outputs`, but rather how to get the class #50 from ImageNet. Which should not be so difficult? I expect a simple filter on the input images using the assigned label. Is this correct? If you really want to use the output of GoogLeNet, it will be just a predicted class of images of your chosen input. Insofar, GoogLeNet does not play a role here unless you want to predict the classes of your own images and use them for Deep Dream.

Comment: Is this at all relevant? https://www.auduno.com/2015/07/29/visualizing-googlenet-classes/

Answer (score 3):

The question is how to get images of the chosen class `#50: 'American alligator, Alligator mississipiensis'` from ImageNet.

1. Go to https://www.image-net.org/.
2. Go to [Download](https://www.image-net.org/download.php).

##### 202303: This guide is outdated!

The website changed, you can no longer download like in the following steps. It now looks like this:

[image]

> The most highly-used subset of ImageNet is the [ImageNet Large Scale Visual Recognition Challenge (ILSVRC)](https://www.image-net.org/challenges/LSVRC/index.php) 2012-2017 image classification and localization dataset. This dataset spans 1000 object classes and contains 1,281,167 training images, 50,000 validation images and 100,000 test images. This subset is available on [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/c/imagenet-object-localization-challenge/overview/description).
>
> For access to the full ImageNet dataset and other commonly used subsets, please login or request access. In doing so, you will need to agree to our terms of access.

##### The following steps are outdated, the website changed:

3. Follow the instructions for "Download Image URLs":

[image]

> How to download the URLs of a synset from your Brower?
>
> ```
> 1. Type a query in the Search box and click "Search" button
> ```

[image]

[image]

The alligator is not shown. `ImageNet is under maintenance. Only ILSVRC synsets are included in the search results.` No problem, we are fine with the similar animal "alligator lizard", since this search is about getting to the right branch of the WordNet treemap. I do not know whether you will get the direct ImageNet images here even if there were no maintenance.

> ```
> 2. Open a synset papge
> ```

[image]

Scrolling down:

[image]

Scrolling down:

[image]

Searching for the American alligator, which happens to be a saurian diapsid reptile as well, as a near neighbour:

[image]

> ```
> 3. You will find the "Download URLs" button under the left-bottom corner of the image browsing window.
> ```

[image]

You will get all of the URLs with the chosen class. A text file pops up in the browser:

http://image-net.org/api/text/imagenet.synset.geturls?wnid=n01698640

We see here that it is  just about knowing the right WordNet id that needs to be put at the end of the URL.

#### Manual image download

The text file looks as follows:

[image]

- http://farm1.static.flickr.com/136/326907154_d975d0c944.jpg
- http://weeksbay.org/photo_gallery/reptiles/American20Alligator.jpg
- ...
- till image number 1261.

As an example, the first URL links to:

[image]

And the second is a dead link:

[image]

The third link is dead, but the fourth is working.

[image]

The images of these URLs are publicly available, but many links are dead, and the pictures are of lower resolution.

#### Automated image download

From the ImageNet guide again:

> How to download by HTTP protocol? To download a synset by HTTP
> request, you need to obtain the "WordNet ID" (wnid) of a synset first.
> When you use the explorer to browse a synset, you can find the WordNet
> ID below the image window.(Click Here and search "Synset WordNet ID"
> to find out the wnid of "Dog, domestic dog, Canis familiaris" synset).
> To learn more about the "WordNet ID", please refer to
>
> ```
> Mapping between ImageNet and WordNet
> ```
>
> Given the wnid of a synset, the URLs of its images can be obtained at
>
> ```
> http://www.image-net.org/api/text/imagenet.synset.geturls?wnid=[wnid]
> ```
>
> **You can also get the hyponym synsets given wnid, please refer to API
> documentation** to learn more.

So what is in that [API documentation](http://image-net.org/download-API)?

There is everything needed to get all of the WordNet IDs (so called "synset IDs") and their words for all synsets, that is, it has any class name and its WordNet ID at hand, for free.

> Obtain the words of a synset
>
> Given the wnid of a synset, the words of
> the synset can be obtained at
>
> ```
> http://www.image-net.org/api/text/wordnet.synset.getwords?wnid=[wnid]
> ```
>
> You can also [Click Here](http://image-net.org/archive/words.txt) to
> download the mapping between WordNet ID and words for all synsets,
> [Click Here](http://image-net.org/archive/gloss.txt) to download the
> mapping between WordNet ID and glosses for all synsets.

If you know the WordNet ids of choice and their class names, you can use the nltk.corpus.wordnet of "nltk" (natural language toolkit), see the [WordNet interface](https://www.nltk.org/howto/wordnet.html).

In our case, we just need the images of class `#50: 'American alligator, Alligator mississipiensis'`, we already know what we need, thus we can leave the nltk.corpus.wordnet aside (see tutorials or Stack Exchange questions for more). We can automate the download of all alligator images by looping through the URLs that are still alive. We *could* also widen this to the full WordNet with a loop over all WordNet IDs, of course, though this would take far too much time for the whole treemap - and is also not recommended since the images will stop being there if 1000s of people download them daily.

I am afraid I will not take the time to write this Python code that accepts the ImageNet class number "#50" as the argument, though that should be possible as well, using mapping tables from WordNet to ImageNet. Class name and WordNet ID should be enough.

For a single WordNet ID, the code could be as follows:

```
import urllib.request 
import csv

wnid = "n01698640"
url = "http://image-net.org/api/text/imagenet.synset.geturls?wnid=" + str(wnid)

# From https://stackoverflow.com/a/45358832/6064933
req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
with open(wnid + ".csv", "wb") as f:
    with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as r:
        f.write(r.read())

with open(wnid + ".csv", "r") as f:
    counter = 1
    for line in f.readlines():      
        print(line.strip("\n"))
        failed = []
        try:
            with urllib.request.urlopen(line) as r2:
                with open(f'''{wnid}_{counter:05}.jpg''', "wb") as f2:
                    f2.write(r2.read())
        except:
            failed.append(f'''{counter:05}, {line}'''.strip("\n"))
        counter += 1
        if counter == 10:
            break

with open(wnid + "_failed.csv", "w", newline="") as f3:
    writer = csv.writer(f3)
    writer.writerow(failed)
```

Result:

[image]

4. If you need the images even behind the dead links and in original quality, and if your project is non-commercial, you can sign in, see "How do I get a copy of the images?" at the [Download FAQ](http://image-net.org/download-faq).

- In the URL above, you see the `wnid=n01698640` at the end of the URL which is the WordNet id that is mapped to ImageNet.
- Or in the "Images of the Synset" tab, just click on "Wordnet IDs".

[image]

To get to:

[image]

or right-click -- save as:

[image]

You can use the WordNet id to get the original images.

[image]

If you are commercial, I would say contact the ImageNet team.

---

#### Add-on

Taking up the idea of a comment: If you do not want many images, but just the "one single class image" that represents the class as much as possible, have a look at [Visualizing GoogLeNet Classes](https://www.auduno.com/2015/07/29/visualizing-googlenet-classes/) and try to use this method with the images of ImageNet instead. Which is using the deepdream code as well.

> Visualizing GoogLeNet Classes
>
> 29. July 2015
>
> Ever wondered what a deep neural network thinks a Dalmatian should
> look like? Well, wonder no more.
>
> Recently Google [published a post](https://googleresearch.blogspot.no/2015/06/inceptionism-going-deeper-into-neural.html) describing how they managed to use
> deep neural networks to generate class visualizations and modify
> images through the so called “inceptionism” method. They later
> published the code to modify images via the inceptionism method
> yourself, however, they didn’t publish code to generate the class
> visualizations they show in the same post.
>
> While I never figured out exactly how Google generated their class
> visualizations, after butchering the [deepdream code](https://github.com/google/deepdream) and this [ipython
> notebook](https://github.com/kylemcdonald/deepdream/blob/master/dream.ipynb) from Kyle McDonald, I managed to coach GoogLeNet into drawing
> these:
>
> [image]
>
> ... [with many other example images to follow]

Comment: the website is different now. Going to ,Download'  does not give this page. How can I downlaod only images and annotations from classes I need ?

Comment: @thestruggleisreal You are right, I changed the answer. I do not know how to get it back without doing what they ask for: register and login.