# How to use URLLib.request to loop through URL's and download images?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, urllib

My current program looks like this

```
import os
import urllib.request


baseUrl = "https://website.com/wp-content/upload/xxx/yyy/zzz-%s.jpg"

for i in range(1,48):
    url = baseUrl % i
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(baseUrl, os.path.basename(url))
```

I haven't coded python in a long time, but I wrote this using urllib2 back when I used to use Python2.7.

It is supposed to replace the %s in the URL and loop through 1-48, and download all the images to the directory that the script is in. But i get alot of errors.

edit : Here is the error that is thrown.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "download.py", line 9, in <module>
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, os.path.basename(url))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 247, in urlretrieve
    with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 531, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 641, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 569, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 649, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Comment: notice you are passing `baseUrl` into the network call.  `baseUrl` is not the `url`, it is your format string and still has the `zzz-%s.jpg` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

`urllib.request` is only available on Python 3 so you have to run the code in Python 3.

Comment: Yes. I'm running on Python 3.7.4 right now but the code isn't working. it says that urllib has no attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Simple fix, if you pass the correct string:

```
 urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, os.path.basename(url))
```

The documentation says urlretrieve is a Legacy carryover, so you might want to find a different way to do this.

I found this alternate approach modified from another SO answer:

```
import os
import requests
baseUrl = "https://website.com/wp-content/upload/xxx/yyy/zzz-%s.jpg"
for i in range(1,48):
    url = baseUrl % i
    r = requests.get(url)
    open(os.path.basename(url), 'wb').write(r.content)
```

Comment: Still not working. i've replaced the baseUrl in that line with url, and i'm still getting the errors.

Comment: Do you know of a non-legacy way to do this?

Comment: You didn't do much research.  Stack Overflow has several questions about Error 403 and urlretrieve.  Here's one:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45358126/http-error-403-forbidden-while-downloading-file-using-urllib

Comment: Modified answer to non-legacy approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `requests` module:

```
import requests
baseUrl = "https://website.com/wp-content/upload/xxx/yyy/zzz-%s.jpg"

for i in range(1,48):
    url = baseUrl % i
    response = requests.get(url)
    my_raw_data = response.content
    with open(os.path.basename(url), 'wb') as my_data:
        my_data.write(my_raw_data)
    my_data.close()
```

Just to add, you must use `url` in the request, not the `baseUrl` as shown in your code :

```
import os
import urllib.request


baseUrl = "https://website.com/wp-content/upload/xxx/yyy/zzz-%s.jpg"

for i in range(1,48):
    url = baseUrl % i
    #urllib.request.urlretrieve(baseUrl, os.path.basename(url))
    #Use This line :
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, os.path.basename(url))
```

Run this in **Python 3**