# Access and download file from web (wordpress server) - HTTP Error 403 Forbidden

Tags: wordpress, python-2.7, gravity-forms-plugin

I have a wordpress site with a form in it from Gravity Forms. In some of the form fields, users are required to upload a file. I'm using the GF API to retrieve the form entries, specifically the fields where users had to upload files, with python's `urllib.urlopener`.

Similar to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34957748/http-error-403-forbidden), I try retrieving and writing the file to my local drive, but the problem is I get this as an error:

`IOError: ('http error', 403, 'Forbidden', <httplib.HTTPMessage instance at 0x0000000004770C88>)`

This only happens with the URLs of the uploaded files from the entries. All other public PDFs work and I'm able to write them to my drive with `response.content`.

I've added headers to the `urllib.URLopener.addheader` object. But why am I forbidden?

Answer (score 0):

The issue wasn't that I had forbidden access. I knew that from the get go.

The fix is to use requests as shown in the second example of the top solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685790/adding-header-to-python-requests-module) but add your headers in dict format like so:

```
headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36','Content-Type': 'application/pdf'}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
with open(saver, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(r.content)
```

`urllib` don't work... still don't know why though.